# Error authenticating with server, but with Postman if I get an answer

Tags: php, curl

good afternoon, I am trying to create a connection to a server, for that I have to pass my access credentials (username y password) and an XML file. My access data is proofreader, but the server is rejecting me, I made the connection with Postman and returned me correct answer.

I need to track the error and know why I am not making the connection.

I share my code that I have so far and I attach the error you are sending me.

> PHP Code (cURL)

```
<?php
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <methodCall>
     <methodName>listAccounts</methodName>
     <params>
      <param>
       <value>
        <struct>
         <member>
          <name>i_account</name>
          <value>
           <int>2763</int>
          </value>
         </member>
        </struct>
       </value>
      </param>
     </params>
    </methodCall>';

    $url = 'https://sip.serv.net.mx/xmlapi/xmlapi';

    $username = "ABACOM";
    $password = "PASSWORD";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo($result);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
```

> Error 401

[image]

> Postman configuration

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your credentials are being treated as a string with the contents "$username:$password" instead of being parsed.

Try:

```
$credentials = "{$username}:{$password}";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials);
```

Note the lack of quotes.

Comment: Try the way you posted but still make the same mistake.

Comment: Hmm, the only other thing I could think to try is changing this:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);`

to this:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);`

Comment: I am a little desperate because it is not yet.